# Using controlBus from spring DSL with parameters

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I need to control my routes and I am using spring DSL for Camel.

I need to exposed a service which will perform thoses actions to the routeId given in paramaters.

The following code does not work (the body contain the routeId)

```
<route id="stopRoute">
            <from uri="direct:stopRoute"/>
            <log message="about to stop a route"/>

            <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=${body}&amp;action=stop"/>
            <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=${body}&amp;action=status"/>

</route>
```

I also tried with simple language but I can't figure out the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Use `<toD>` to make the to dynamic.

Comment: Thanks that's work, I had'nt seen this new expression, that's explaining while old examples does not work with dynamic URI.

Comment: By the way do you know if the stopRoute or any other controlBus action could disable the server connector in http cases?